# Is there a name for this Rubik's cube algorithm?

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm

$RUR'U RU2R'$

I use this algorithm to:

- permute UL and UF edges (messing up corners)
- orient LL from a fish (possibly using its mirror)
- orient pairs of LL corners by combining above algorithm with its mirror

I was convinced there is an established name for this algorithm, but can't find any.

**Does anybody know the name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This move sequence is usually called ["Sune"](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sune).